# Active record association with named_scope repeat condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have relation like user has many articles and articles belong to user.
So, to find the articles(which are active) of user i had added named_scope in articles model

```
named_scope :active_articles, :conditions => "active = true"
```

and when do-

```
user.articles.active_articles
```

It gives properly as expected but on console query have repeat condition-

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE (`articles`.user_id = 52) AND ((active = true) AND (`articles`.user_id = 52))
```

how to restrict to repeat of condition ?
or
How to add condition to association ?

I am working with rails 2.3.5.Thanks in advance.

Comment: My $0.02: trust the query optimizer and not worry about it.  If you are using a database like PostgreSQL, you can do "analyze" and see that the two queries are going to be exactly the same (I predict).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think the reason that it is repeated is because the first part 
"user.articles will generate WHERE (`articles`.user_id = 52)" 
and the second part
"articles.active_articles will generate AND ((active = true) AND (`articles`.user_id = 52))"

so when you call both part user.articles.active_articles
it will generate (`articles`.user_id = 52) AND ((active = true) AND (`articles`.user_id = 52))

Can you call article.active_articles? and post the result?

Comment: How it will work? it always give undefind method active_articles?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't wrote clearly, I mean may be you have to find the specific article and then article.active_articles, so it will not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following has_many association in you User model:

```
has_many :active_articles, :conditions => {:active => true }, :class_name => "Article"
```

And then access the active articles via user.active_articles directly.

I know it is not as good as named_scope on the Article model but it does eliminate the duplication of conditionals in the SQL query which is generated by ActiveRecord

Comment: Ya this will work but i am looking for the best way and why rails add extra conditions.